# Rails: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rendering form like that:

```
= f.fields_for :files do |files_form|
  = render('file_form', f: files_form)
```

In the _file_form.html.slim I have such a code:

```
- id = f.object.id
- file= f.object.files.first

li.panel.panel-default
  .panel-heading role="tab" id="heading"
    a.file-heading data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#files" href="#collapse#{id}"
      div.clearfix role="button"
        span = f.object.name
  .panel-collapse.collapse-in id="collapse#{id}" role="tabpanel"
    .panel-body
      .clearfix = link_to(t('shared.destroy'), '#', class:'btn btn-warning btn-sm discard-file pull-right')
      .form-group
        = f.label(:name, t('activerecord.attributes.file.name'))
        = f.text_field(:name, class: 'form-control')
        = f.label(file.id) //my problem
```

everything works fine until I try to get label with the file id.

> Error message: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

It looks like is not initialized but actually, when I check it in debugger before line with **file.id**, it is initialized and I can easily check it value.

When I'm using **:id** instead of **file.id**, everything work fine. Why?

Why file is nil class when i trying to retrieve id (or any other data) from it?

Comment: can you post the value of id and file after inspecting?

Comment: is this for a create or an edit?

Answer (score 0):

Your `files` collection is empty. Therefore when you do `file = f.object.files.first`, the `file` local variable gets assigned `nil`.

When you try to access it as an object having an attribute with the name `id` it expectedly throws.

Depending on your use case you can either bail if there are no elements in collection or use a technique to handle `nil` value:

```
f.label(file.try(:id))
```

or

```
f.label(file&.id) # Ruby 2.3.0 and up
```

or

```
f.label(file.id rescue 'placeholder label')
```

**UPDATE**

For `fields_for` to work, the parent model needs to accept the attributes for its associated objects that you use. Make sure you have this in your parent model:

```
has_many :files
accepts_nested_attributes_for :files
```

Unless the latter line is there, the form object will be nil, which may be the reason for the behaviour you're observing.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, now I get error 'undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: See my updated answer. Also please add your models associations definition to your question, as well as full error output in case there are more errors.